# lendo retorno json_encode php com ajax

Tags: ajax

Recebo este retorno com o json_encode pelo php mas nao estou conseguindo ler ele no ajax success, o que estou fazendo de errado?

```
{"id":"1","id_pesquisa":"3","id_pergunta":"7","id_resposta":"31","mostrar":"1","ocultar":"2"},
{"id":"2","id_pesquisa":"3","id_pergunta":"8","id_resposta":"31","mostrar":"2","ocultar":"1"}

var direcao = $.ajax({
  type : 'get',
  url: 'dadosPS.php?ps=direcionamento',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {

  },success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
      console.log(data[i].id);
    }
  },error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

  }
});
```

Comment: qual é o erro que te mostra no console ?

Comment: Retorna este erro :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '185' in {"id":"1","id_pesquisa":"3","id_pergunta":"7","id_resposta":"31","mostrar":"1","ocultar":"2"}{"id":"2","id_pesquisa":"3","id_pergunta":"8","id_resposta":"31","mostrar":"2","ocultar":"1"}

Comment: É verdade, se tiver algum erro o json pode não mostrar corretamente, verifique essa linha 185 e analise essa palavra in

Comment: Se for esse JSON.. ele está ERRADO! Use o jsonlint para validar o teu JSON.

Comment: Além de corrigir seu arquivo php, tenta também usar no javascript o `dataType: 'json'`,  JSON para json (em caixa baixa)

Comment: Bom fiz as correções mas nada de funcionar, como o william falou deve estar errado este JSON. @WilliamAparecidoBrandino, qual seria o formato correto para ler?

Comment: Instala o postman e cola essa url lá pra ver ou que acontece o cola no teu navegador mesmo e ver o que retorna

Comment: @CarlosLopes Neste caso, deve estar entre colchetes.

Answer (score 0):

Tente retornar só o dado no `success` e dentro você faz o for:

```
...
   /* resto do codigo */
    success: function (data) {
       $.each(data, function(i, j)){
         console.log( j.id );
        }
     }

...
```

Pelo menos comigo funciona assim

Answer (score 0):

acho que não estas a usar a variável direcao por isso removi-a, podes sempre remover as funções que não suas, assim:

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'GET',
  url: 'dadosPS.php?ps=direcionamento',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function (data) {
     var data = JSON.parse(data);
     $.each(data, function(i, v)){
         console.log( v.id );
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: Quando utilizo dataType:JSON , não ocorre erro, mas no console nao aparece nada...

Comment: editei a resposta. tenta assim

Comment: permanece o mesmo , no console não aparece nada. acho que este retorno json deve estar errado.

Comment: é o mais provável

Answer (score 0):

Segue a solução:
Ajustado json para -> `{"data":[{"id":"1","id_pesquisa":"3","id_pergunta":"7","id_resposta":"31","mostrar":"1","ocultar":"2"},{"id":"2","id_pesquisa":"3","id_pergunta":"8","id_resposta":"31","mostrar":"2","ocultar":"1"}]}`

```
//Direcionamnetos
       $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url: 'dadosPS.php?ps=direcionamento',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

               $.each(data.data, function(key, val){
                  console.log(val.id);
              });

            }
          });
```

A todos Obrigado pelas sugestões !!!!

Comment: nao precisaria necessariamente retornar a data no php, mas que bom que funcionou.